# Deplearning4j on Spark pipeline; Recurrent Neural Network program slow downs when added to spark pipeline

Tags: performance, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

I created a RNN program which creates an RNN model, trains it and predicts using the model using deeplearning4j. It runs with a good speed(30 minutes)but when it is added to the spark pipeline, it takes about 10 hours to run.Can you give me reason for that?

Comment: Show some relevant code part which you think may be problamatic

Comment: The only change which I have done is adding the program to the Spark pipeline.

Comment: This is to broad. Are you running Spark in standalone, on Hadoop,.... If on Hadoop which scheduler etc. Based on your question the best tip is probably: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Profiling+Spark+Applications+Using+YourKit

Comment: Please join the community on Gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j